# How to debug redirect uris in Spring Security oauth2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reverse-proxy, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Security to setup oauth2 authentication within my Spring Boot web app that runs behind a reverse proxy.

Flow:

1) Navigate to my Spring app's login page

2) Redirection to oauth provider. Logging in.

3) Redirection back to my redirect-uri endpoint

4) Flow breaks and default Spring login page prints:

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter]
```

I turned on debugging, the console shows:

```
2019-01-30 09:46:40.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider
2019-01-30 09:46:40.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider
2019-01-30 09:46:40.095 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter] 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:136) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

Digging into `OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java`'s code shows that the following statement triggers the error: (`authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri().equals(authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri())`)

I checked the browser requests. The redirect uri parameter of my initial request is equal to the site I'm redirected after being authenticated at the provider's site. (Otherwise the provider would have thrown an redirect uri mismatch error).

According to another user's experience (http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2018/08/10/lessons-learnt-of-spring-boot-oauth2-redirect-uris/) Spring Boot sees 'localhost' when running behind a reverse proxy and therefore the redirect-uri aren't equal anymore (when localhost is not the correct hostname).

How can I get the value of `authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri()` and `authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri()`? I want to see which redirect uri Spring Security sees. The debug console doesn't print these values.

Comment: were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I created an endpoint that prints out request.getRequestURL().toString() and indeed it prints the original url and not the reverse proxy url. That might be the problem.